# Why and when to use transclusion in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently, I'm learning AngularJS and I'm trying to understand transclusion feature. I've read different articles about transclusion and I now understand the difference between `transclude: true` and `transclude: 'element'`.

However, what is not clear for me is when I should use it. There are a lot of articles around, but I can find practical use cases in real world.

So, I would really appreciate if someone can help me and demonstrate real-world example of using transclusion and answer the following questions:

1. Does tranclusion have benefits regarding to performance?
2. Why not simply use `ng-repeat` and not `cloneFn` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, `transclude:true` is used when you need a **container**. Which means, you do not know what the users of your directive would put into your container. An example is a dialog box, which has common parts including header, close button, etc. But you do not want to limit the things that could be put into this dialog box. In this case, using `transclude:true`, such that you can put ***whatever arbitrary*** content inside the directive.

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

> We've seen that you can pass in models to a directive using the
>   isolate scope, but sometimes it's desirable to be able to pass in an
>   entire template rather than a string or an object. Let's say that we
>   want to create a "dialog box" component. The dialog box should be able
>   to wrap any arbitrary content.

It is more or less not a performance consideration. Just introduce the flexibility to directives.

`ng-repeat` is a different story. It is used to iterate some iteratable collections.